# Generating random graph with low degree Java

Tags: java, graph, random, coordinates, points

I am trying to generate a graph with vertices having random coordinates and very low degree distribution. This network must look similar to road networks. The drawing etc is done automatically I just need to create very random numbers for the coordinates and make sure they do not overlap. How can I achieve this? Currently I have:

```
public void graphGenerator(int size) {
    Point test = new Point();
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        test.x = random.nextInt(1000);
        test.y = random.nextInt(700);

        String name = Integer.toString(i);
        Vertex v = new Vertex(name, test.x, test.y);
        vertices.add(v);
    }
}
```

My graph class has a list of vertices and edges: List vertices; and     private List edges;

My edge class stores: vertex source, vertex target, vertex weight.
My vertex class stores: string name, int x, int y, List of adjacent edges.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your current output looks like and what is wrong with it?  As far as I can tell, what you have here should be accomplishing your goal (aside from the fact that the `name` variable isn't used).

Comment: Currently this outputs 20 vertices at random positions onto the JFrame. I now need to link up these vertices with edges with low degree so they look similar to road networks (this must be random and done automatically with no user input).

Comment: Your vertices variable is undefined. Shouldn't this generator return a graph rather than a void? I don't see how your code is communicating to the graph what the edges in the graph are. There is a lot more to a graph than a collection of vertices. Please add a Graph object to the example so that we can see what your graph *is*.
Consider using a static variable for random and initializing only once, this was once needed, now it is more of a style issue.

Comment: I have updated the original post.

Comment: @ Garret Hall: preferably not, but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: @ Garret Hall: I no longer require the edges not to overlap. However, it would be great if the overlapping was little.